# Is it possible to pass parameters to a folder or a file in c#

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, parameters

I know that you can launch batch files (.bat) and executable files (.exe) while passing parameters to them. However, I would like to know if it is directly possible to send parameters to other types of files (e.g. .docx or .txt) or even an specific folder (e.g. maximizing it).

The c# code is something like this:

```
string targetPath= "something";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(targetPath);
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1 param2";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: What would you expect a folder to do with these parameters? Are you talking about opening an Explorer folder with a given file selected in it?

Comment: You can write a console app that outputs the command line arguments to the console. Then another app that launches the first one. If you successfully passed the arguments then you'll see them in the console output.

Comment: For folder only maximizing and minimizing is in my mind. I know that you can do it in other ways, but I want to know if it is possible by sending a parameter.

Comment: But a folder cannot maximize/minimize itself - I don‘t know what that should be anyway - within the context of explorer it makes sense to maximize/minimize the window which is showing the folder.

Comment: Yes, by maximizing a folder I meant maximizing its explorer window. I think the only way (if exists) should be to pass parameters to explorer.exe and it is not possible to pass it directly to the folder path.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks, That's a good idea. I will try to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files and folders cannot receive command line arguments.

Files and folders aren't programs, they don't receive anything on a command line. If you launch cmd.exe and type `mytextfile.txt` windows launches the default program associated with a `.txt` extension with the path to `mytextfile.txt` as a command line parameter. This is a feature of cmd.exe. If you try `Process.Start()` with FileName pointing to a non-executable file, an exception is thrown.

Maximizing a window could be done through the windows C api's [`ShowWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Using this in c# would require p/Invoke.